# How can I check which coop missions I have gold medal in Red Dead Redemption?

Tags: red-dead-redemption, achievements

In the coop missions from the "Outlaws To The End" DLC.

Answer (score 2):

Unfortunately, you cannot see which missions you have obtained gold medals on; this feature does not exist.

Answer (score 0):

If you set up your [Social Club](http://socialclub.rockstargames.com/games/rdr/) account and all that jazz you can go to the [Multiplayer Leaderboards](http://socialclub.rockstargames.com/games/rdr/multiplayer.html) section and choose the leaderboard for the mission you're interested in, your rank awards show up there, in the second table labeled "Your Leaderboard"

If that's not the info you're looking for, that page currently has a message on it saying that you'll be able to see your Rank and Award emblems on that page soon, but not yet.

Comment: Unfortunately it doesn't show medals. Those awards are something else.